# Installation of modules from cpan mirror not working

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl so please bear with me.

I have tried to use minicpan on a Linux machine with no access to internet.  I did this by creating a repository on a windows machine with internet successfully using `minicpan -l C:/MINICPAN/ -r http://mirror.optusnet.com.au/CPAN`, and then copying `C:/MINICPAN/` to the Linux box (`/opt/perlLib/MINICPAN/`).

The problem is, if I use `cpanm --mirror file:///opt/perlLib/MINICPAN Net::SSH::Perl` it just hangs.

If I use `cpanm --mirror file:///opt/perlLib/MINICPAN -L /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/ Net::SSH::Perl` I get the following but it just hangs after that:

```
==> Found dependencies: ExtUtils::MakeMaker, ExtUtils::Install
```

If I use `cpanm --mirror file:///opt/perlLib/MINICPAN Net::SSH::Perl --mirror-only` I get:
`Net::SSH::Perl is up to date. (1.36)`

I am using v5.8.8 built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi

Is there an path issue that needs fixing?  Is it a version problem (my windows box is using perl 5.18).

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per the [cpanm documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/App-cpanminus-1.7001/bin/cpanm), you are correct to use `--mirror-only`; it says: "Select this option if you are using a local mirror of CPAN, such as minicpan when you're offline". Without `--mirror-only` it presumably is hanging trying to connect to the internet.

With `--mirror-only` you are told that you have an up-to-date version of Net::SSH::Perl - are you sure that you don't have it installed? What happens if you try with `--mirror-only` and some other module?